# DOM// return values back to input for edit: https://codepen.io/iacob24/pen/BPmGaW

Tags: javascript, dom

I built a phone book app but it seems that my edit button does not work. It should return the values from the row back to inputs for editing. Codepen in title. Thank you!

Comment: show your Code here

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Get the code here: https://codepen.io/iacob24/pen/BPmGaW

Comment: I still didn't manage how to add code in Body when posting :(  link code in title...

Comment: @unkuser1234 Click the `{}` button after selecting your code.  Questions that link to an off-site resource will be closed if they don't include the relevant details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using id instead of className in row 39 and 40.
Also change "hrIndex" to "rowIndex".

Comment: I changed rows 39 and 40 and also below in code; also switched to "rowIndex".. but all it does now when I press Edit is to change the value on button Add Contact to Save...  https://codepen.io/iacob24/pen/BPmGaW

Answer (score 0):

Forked it and gave a slightly different implementation, check it out see what you think.  Instead of walking the DOM like your example I placed the click event handler on the row since it contains all the elements that will be manipulated.  The when buttons in the rows are clicked they bubble up and the row handles the event based on the button with classes ['edit', 'save', 'delete'] for edit the actual row changes from text to input fields and the save button is added to the row, for the save button the reverse happens.  The delete button just deletes the row.

```
function deleteRow(row) {
  let tbodyEl = document.querySelector('#entriesTable tbody');
  tbodyEl.removeChild(row);
}

function resaveRow(row) {
  let tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
  let nameInp = tds[0].querySelector('input');
  let phoneInp = tds[1].querySelector('input');
  let name = nameInp.value;
  let phone = phoneInp.value;
  let saveBtn = tds[2].querySelector('.save');
  tds[0].removeChild(nameInp);
  tds[1].removeChild(phoneInp);
  tds[0].innerText = name;
  tds[1].innerText = phone;
  tds[2].removeChild(saveBtn);
};

function editRow(row) {
  let tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
  let name = tds[0].innerText;
  let phone = tds[1].innerText;
  let nameInp = document.createElement('input');
  nameInp.value = name;
  let phoneInp = document.createElement('input');
  phoneInp.value = phone;
  let saveBtn = document.createElement('button');
  saveBtn.innerText = 'Save';
  saveBtn.classList.add('save');

  tds[0].innerHTML = "";
  tds[0].appendChild(nameInp);
  tds[1].innerHTML = "";
  tds[1].appendChild(phoneInp);
  tds[2].appendChild(saveBtn);
}

function rowHandler(e) {
  let clickedEl = e.target;
  if (clickedEl.classList.contains('edit')) {
    //this is the edit button handler
    editRow(this);
  }
  if (clickedEl.classList.contains('delete')) {
    //this is the delete handler
    deleteRow(this);
  }
  if (clickedEl.classList.contains('save')) {
    //this is the resave after editing handler
    resaveRow(this);
  }
}

function addContact(){
  let tbodyEl = document.querySelector('#entriesTable tbody');
  let nameEl = document.getElementById('insertName');
  let phoneEl = document.getElementById('insertPhone');
  let phone = phoneEl.value;
  let name = nameEl.value;

  if (name !== '' && phone !== '') {
    let row = document.createElement('tr');
    let nameTd = document.createElement('td');
    let phoneTd = document.createElement('td');
    let editTd = document.createElement('td');
    let deleteTd = document.createElement('td');
    let editBtn = document.createElement('button');
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
    editBtn.classList.add('edit');
    deleteBtn.classList.add('delete');
    editBtn.innerText = 'Edit';
    deleteBtn.innerText = 'Delete';
    nameTd.innerText = name;
    phoneTd.innerText = phone;
    editTd.appendChild(editBtn);
    deleteTd.appendChild(deleteBtn);
    row.appendChild(nameTd);
    row.appendChild(phoneTd);
    row.appendChild(editTd);
    row.appendChild(deleteTd);
    row.addEventListener('click', rowHandler);
    tbodyEl.appendChild(row);
    nameEl.value = '';
    phoneEl.value = '';
  }
}

document.getElementById('addContact').addEventListener('click', addContact);
```

Forked the Pen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djZwqm